# How to add a button to sprite-kit programmatically with swift?

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit

I want to add a button programmatically in sprite-kit
until now I was able to get to this point:

This is right after the class:

```
var button: SKNode!
```

Then in the `didMoveToView` method I have this:

```
button = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44))
button.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(frame), y: CGRectGetMaxY(frame))
addChild(button)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button isn't displayed, because of its position.

e.g, write

```
button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
```

and the button appears at the center of your SKScene.

Comment: Do you have any other nodes in the scene? Set button.zPosition = x, where x is int, bigger than any other node's zPosition.

Comment: unbelievable I moved the node around the code (made it the first and the last node and that didn't work , but when I used zposition it worked !)